# A clarification on linear properties of modular arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, linear-transformations

Suppose $p,p',p'',q,q',q'',q_1,q_1',q_1'',r$ are integers with $0<q,q',q_1,q_1',q_1''<r<p,p',p''$ and
$$pq+p'q'+p''q''=pq_1+p'q_1'+p''q_1''=t$$

If $m=p\bmod r$, $m'=p'\bmod r$, $m''=p''\bmod r$ where $0\leq m,m',m''<r$ holds then there are $k,k',k''$ such that 
$$p=m+kr,\quad p'=m'+k'r,\quad p''=m''+k''r$$

Is there always two *different* integers $n,n_1$ such that 
$$mq+m'q'+m''q''=\ell+n r$$
$$mq_1+m'q_1'+m''q_1''=\ell+n_1 r$$
holds where $\ell=t\bmod r$ and $0\leq \ell<r$?

Can we give explicit formula for $n,n_1$?

Comment: Confusion arises with these strokes.  What should write the equation or system to solve it.  Then select those solutions which are necessary.

Comment: @individ I have no idea what you wrote.